# How to fetch data from a firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so im trying to connect to the database. So, that you will be able to search people who are present on the database on the search bar.
However it is still not connecting

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var postData = [String]()
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     // let db = Firestore.firestore()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("users").observe(DataEventType .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            // code to execute when child added under users
            let post = snapshot.value as? String
            if let actualPost = post {
                self.postData.append(actualPost)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post rest of code ................

Comment: this is all of the code for the searchviewcontroller. Am I missing something here?

Comment: where are table methods ?

Comment: I didnt add any. How do we implement them?

Comment: "it is still not connecting" - how do you know this?